# Java Objective-C Json data

Tags: java, objective-c, json

I have a little problem with understanding this too lines of code in Objective-C :

```
id jsonData;
NSInteger errorCode;
NSString* errorString;
errorCode = [jsonData sqlInt:@"error_code"];
errorString = [[jsonData objectForKey:@"error_string"] retain];
```

I'm trying to find a way how to do the same code in Java,that's why I need a little help to understand this piece of code.
Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT:**
Is this code do the same as in Objective C?  :

```
 ErrorCode = new JSONObject();
    ErrorCode.put("error_code", errorCode);
    ErrorString = new JSONObject();
    ErrorString.put("error_string", errorString);
```

Comment: what json library are you using for Java?

Comment: Actually I'm using json library for Android build in Android SDK.

Comment: also what does your json look like?

Comment: Actually I don't have the json yet,it's a Objective C code which I have to translate to Java code.And I'm trying to find what these few lines are doing.

Comment: its taking the json data out. its really hard to do anything without specifics.

Comment: I have only this code..the rest of the code is checking the errorCode in switch statement and trying to find the type of it.

Comment: i have only this definiton about jsonData,which I put in the question..I know it's hard to understand what exactly to do with this code...That's why I'm asking it here..Thanks for the patience and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,

```
SBJSON *jsonData = [SBJSON alloc]init]; - Objective c

private JSONObject jObject; - Java
```

// you get a JSON Data - Objective C

```
NSDictionary *errorString = [[jsonData objectForKey:@"error_string"] retain];
```

For Java -

```
jObject = new JSONObject(errorString); 

JSONArray menuitemArray = popupObject.getJSONArray("error_string");

String attributeValue = jObject.getString("value");

System.out.println(attributeValue);
```

Comment: @Bombastic : hey you need to get the data first from the datasource url refer your objective c code , then try this link to get a java String response then proceeed to steps i wrote above . http://androidmaterial.blogspot.com/2011/08/json-parsing-in-android.html

Comment: @Bombastic : one thing is about [jsonData sqlInt:@"error_code"]; do u find any details abt that - so that we can confirm solutions what it can be - i guess it s some method to trace error code signs!

Comment: @Bombastic : Sometimes JSON Result depends on the error codes of the api call ,

Comment: Actually I look all over the code and trying to find in all files, but the only thing that I found was : id jsonData; and this :  @property (nonatomic, readonly) id jsonData; Nothing else...

Comment: @Bombastic let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2998/discussion-between-karthikeyan-and-bombastic)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your jsonData is in a dictionary of some sort, and presumably sqlInt is either a "category" extension to NSDictionary or a method of some custom dictionary class that is being used by the JSON parser.  From its name it takes a named element of some sort and returns its `int` representation.

So you have two elements in your dictionary, one named "error_code" and one named "error_string".  "error_string" can simply be extracted into a String, but "error_code" is either an Integer object or a String representation of an integer -- can't tell which from your code (but you can tell by looking at the source JSON -- An Integer value will NOT be surrounded by quotes, but a String value will).

Comment: Actually I have only this code jsonData..the declaration and the code similar to errorCode = [jsonData sqlInt:@"error_code"]; .Nothing more.

Comment: You can, of course, test the type of element you receive.  (Note that the Objective-C code you have is for parsing received data, even though your Java is apparently for constructing a new JSON string.)