# how to consume the json web service in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

i am consuming the json webservice .i am assigning the stringurl to nsurl but the nsurl always assigning the null value. also i didn't get the response. can anyone suggest me what is the mistake i done in the following coding

```
- (IBAction)addbutton:(id)sender {

NSString *urltest = @"sample url";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urltest];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];
         NSString *test= [[greeting objectForKey:@"code"] stringValue];
         NSString *test1 = [greeting objectForKey:@"message"];
     }
 }];}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Objective-C Json data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242118/java-objective-c-json-data)

Comment: You should URL-encode yours query in URL. You can use `NSURLComponents` for building `NSURL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL string is invalid, note the part:

```
taxName=ÂU.F¿Kåa¥gh
```

Those characters are not allowed in URL. Fix your URL to a valid URL (e.g. percent-encode parameter values).

E.g. the above with URL encoding would be:

```
taxName=%C3%82U.F%C2%BFK%C3%A5a%C2%A5gh
```

but I am not sure that's correct. The parameter value does not seem to be valid.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply sir can u pls suggest me how i can change that above url as an valid url also i checked above url in rest client i am getting the response.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost:8080/MyWebservice.asmx/GetHelloWorldWithParam";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *myRequestString = @"param="; // Attention HERE!!!!
[myRequestString stringByAppendingString:myParamString];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String] length:[myRequestString length]];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
```

Thank you